# ipa is very large when using single vector mode (xcode 6 + swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, vector

My project use single vector image (pdf format), but ipa exported very large. Should I use vector or @2x @3x for my project?

Comment: how large? I don't see a reason it is caused by pdf.

Comment: I have a image folder(pdf + json) about ~3mb, but when built ipa, it is about ~20mb.

Comment: have you compared with Objective-C version？ I suspect it is because swift. check https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2

Comment: besides, you could take a look at your ipa file and find out if the image and pdf size changing is the reason, which I don't think.

Comment: CHECK THE SIZE ON THE VECTOR IMAGE AND THE `@2X` AND `@3X` IMAGS. IF THAT DIFFERES AND MAY BE THAT CAN HELP YOU

Comment: I decoded ipa and checked, with pdf file is larger than 500px x 500px, xcode will convert to tif file with capacity > ~3mb. I think If the project has large image size, shouldn't use vector.